# How to sync Hadoop configuration files to multiple nodes?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, centos, synchronization, scp

I uesd to manage a cluster of only 3 Centos machines running Hadoop. So `scp` is enough for me to copy the configuration files to the other 2 machines.

However, I have to setup a Hadoop cluster to more than 10 machines. It is really frustrated to sync the files so many times using `scp`.

I want to find a tool that I can easily sync the files to all machines. And the machine names are defined in a config file, such as:

```
node1
node2
...
node10
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use Zookeeper you can modify your hadoop script in `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop` and add something like :

```
if [ "$COMMAND" == "deployConf" ]; then
  for HOST in `cat $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves`
    do
       scp $HADOOP_HOME/conf/mapred-site.xml $HOST:$HADOOP_HOME/conf
       scp $HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml $HOST:$HADOOP_HOME/conf
       scp $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml $HOST:$HADOOP_HOME/conf
    done
    exit 0
fi
```

That's what I'm using now and it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use Zookeeper with Hadoop.

ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services.

Reference: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to do that. One way is to use tools like **rsync**. The Hadoop control scripts can distribute configuration files to all nodes of the cluster using rsync. Alternatively, you can make use of tools like [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cloudera-manager.html) or [Ambari](http://incubator.apache.org/ambari/) if you need a more sophisticated way to achieve that.

Comment: This is discussed at a high-level in Chapter 9 of Tom White's "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" and would be a worthwhile read for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you use InfoSphere BigInsights then there is the script syncconf.sh